# Calculate percentage change from a base date within groups

Tags: r, series

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(cat1 = rep(1:4, each = 6),
                 cat2 = rep(1:2, each = 3,4),
                 day = rep(as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03")),8),
                 x = sample(80:120,24),
                 y = sample(80:120,24))

    cat1    cat2    day             x        y 
1   1       1       01.01.2016      109     106
2   1       1       02.01.2016      115      95
3   1       1       03.01.2016      120     107
4   1       2       01.01.2016      113     100
5   1       2       02.01.2016       96      88
6   1       2       03.01.2016       85      97
7   2       1       01.01.2016       91     118
8   2       1       02.01.2016       97      80
9   2       1       03.01.2016      104      86
10  2       2       01.01.2016      111     101
11  2       2       02.01.2016       81      91
12  2       2       03.01.2016       84      90
13  3       1       01.01.2016      101     105
14  3       1       02.01.2016       80     108
15  3       1       03.01.2016       90      96
16  3       2       01.01.2016       92      83
17  3       2       02.01.2016       89      99
18  3       2       03.01.2016      112     109
19  4       1       01.01.2016      118     111
20  4       1       02.01.2016      100     115
21  4       1       03.01.2016      103      85
22  4       2       01.01.2016       86     112
23  4       2       02.01.2016       98      81
24  4       2       03.01.2016      105     113
```

I need to calculate an index from a fixed date within the dataset over a set of subgroups (cat1, cat2). My desired outcome when indexing on 02.01.2016 looks like this:

```
    cat1    cat2    day             x        y     xi         yi
1   1       1       01.01.2016      109     106    0,94783    1,11579
2   1       1       02.01.2016      115      95    1,00000    1,00000
3   1       1       03.01.2016      120     107    1,04348    1,12632
4   1       2       01.01.2016      113     100    1,17708    1,13636
5   1       2       02.01.2016       96      88    1,00000    1,00000
6   1       2       03.01.2016       85      97    0,88542    1,10227
7   2       1       01.01.2016       91     118    0,93814    1,47500
8   2       1       02.01.2016       97      80    1,00000    1,00000
9   2       1       03.01.2016      104      86    1,07216    1,07500
10  2       2       01.01.2016      111     101    1,37037    1,10989
11  2       2       02.01.2016       81      91    1,00000    1,00000
12  2       2       03.01.2016       84      90    1,03704    0,98901
13  3       1       01.01.2016      101     105    1,26250    0,97222
14  3       1       02.01.2016       80     108    1,00000    1,00000
15  3       1       03.01.2016       90      96    1,12500    0,88889
16  3       2       01.01.2016       92      83    1,03371    0,83838
17  3       2       02.01.2016       89      99    1,00000    1,00000
18  3       2       03.01.2016      112     109    1,25843    1,10101
19  4       1       01.01.2016      118     111    1,18000    0,96522
20  4       1       02.01.2016      100     115    1,00000    1,00000
21  4       1       03.01.2016      103      85    1,03000    0,73913
22  4       2       01.01.2016       86     112    0,87755    1,38272
23  4       2       02.01.2016       98      81    1,00000    1,00000
24  4       2       03.01.2016      105     113    1,07143    1,39506
```

I tried extracting the reference dates for each group with data.table subsets and then using this extracts to calculate indexes but I haven't figured out how to do that properly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you are getting the last two column values?

Comment: @prateek1592 the values of x and y within each subgroup combination are divided by the value of x and y on 02.01.2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly likely this has been answered before, but here are two options  with `dplyr` and `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% 
  mutate(xi = x/x[day=='2016-01-02'], 
         yi = y/y[day=='2016-01-02'])

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, `:=` (xi = x/x[day=='2016-01-02'], 
                  yi = y/y[day=='2016-01-02']), 
          by = .(cat1, cat2)]
```

which results in:

```
    cat1 cat2        day   x   y        xi        yi
 1:    1    1 2016-01-01 109 106 0.9478261 1.1157895
 2:    1    1 2016-01-02 115  95 1.0000000 1.0000000
 3:    1    1 2016-01-03 120 107 1.0434783 1.1263158
 4:    1    2 2016-01-01 113 100 1.1770833 1.1363636
 5:    1    2 2016-01-02  96  88 1.0000000 1.0000000
 6:    1    2 2016-01-03  85  97 0.8854167 1.1022727
 7:    2    1 2016-01-01  91 118 0.9381443 1.4750000
 8:    2    1 2016-01-02  97  80 1.0000000 1.0000000
 9:    2    1 2016-01-03 104  86 1.0721649 1.0750000
10:    2    2 2016-01-01 111 101 1.3703704 1.1098901
11:    2    2 2016-01-02  81  91 1.0000000 1.0000000
12:    2    2 2016-01-03  84  90 1.0370370 0.9890110
13:    3    1 2016-01-01 101 105 1.2625000 0.9722222
14:    3    1 2016-01-02  80 108 1.0000000 1.0000000
15:    3    1 2016-01-03  90  96 1.1250000 0.8888889
16:    3    2 2016-01-01  92  83 1.0337079 0.8383838
17:    3    2 2016-01-02  89  99 1.0000000 1.0000000
18:    3    2 2016-01-03 112 109 1.2584270 1.1010101
19:    4    1 2016-01-01 118 111 1.1800000 0.9652174
20:    4    1 2016-01-02 100 115 1.0000000 1.0000000
21:    4    1 2016-01-03 103  85 1.0300000 0.7391304
22:    4    2 2016-01-01  86 112 0.8775510 1.3827160
23:    4    2 2016-01-02  98  81 1.0000000 1.0000000
24:    4    2 2016-01-03 105 113 1.0714286 1.3950617
```